# Regarding "glue on"

Tags: idioms

Somebody makes a minion using eggs, eyeballs and paints.

They then say, "Then glue on one or two eyeballs".

What is this saying? Is there a difference between "Glue on one or two eyeballs" and "Glue one or two eyeballs"?

Does "Glue on" mean "Put glue on"?

http://ko.englishcentral.com/video/25798

Comment: "Glue on" means to utilize glue to attach the components together.

Comment: "Glue on" means "glue [the object that is to be attached] on [to the surface of the receiving object]."

Comment: To glue sth on /on sth means to use glue so that sth sticks on a surface.

Comment: Compare how the Latin-origin verb **affix** is composed of **ad** (to) + **figere** (to fix).

Answer (score 2):

"Glue *A* on *B*" means "Attach *A* to *B* via glue". 
When somebody says "Glue *A* on" or "Glue on *A*", they mean "Attach *A* onto some other implied object via glue". 
Typically you won't just hear "Glue *A*" (I interpret it as "apply glue to *A*", but to be technical, no dictionaries that I've checked seem to have a definition for such a usage).

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/glue
http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/learner/glue

http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns-with-and-without-objects (this third link has nothing about the word "glue" specifically, but will help if confusion about how it (and verbs like it) work).

Comment: I would also interpret "glue A" as "put some glue on A", but that's a weird thing to do, since glue is for attaching two different things. I guess maybe one could say "Glue A, then attach A."